# Как загнать код файла в переменную, подключенного через require?

Tags: текст, переменные, php, require_once

Всем привет. Вот, например, есть файл с содержимым - например "Тест" и я его подключаю через `require` и как мне этот текст (Тест) загнать в переменную?

Comment: НИКАК! Потому что require(и все в этом роде) не читает содержимого, а тем более не ВОЗВРАЩАЕТ ЕГО!

Answer (score 2):

Похоже на забивание гвоздей [микроскопом](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.include.php), которым стоило бы подключать скрипты. К тому же, надо помнить, что `require()` остановит выполнение, если файла не будет.

Может лучше посмотреть на  [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php)?

Еще:

- [Что-то](http://linux.povorotka.org.ua/page.php?id=293) об оптимизации (искать по словам `file_get_contents`).
- [Тесты](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?851185-include-require-performance) мне проводить лень - попробуйте сами.

Comment: file_get_contents() сильно сервер грузит. Я уже пытался - сказали что ты живешь в 20 веке.

Comment: ммммм.... точно а если подключение файла загнать в буферизацию, а потом все вывлдить??

ob_start();
include './test';
$var = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

Comment: выгляит не очень правдоподобно - ничего сказать не могу

Answer (score 1):

Не усложняйте жизнь file_get_contents или буфером, сделать все можно проще -
содержимое подключаемого файла загоните в return, при подключении его в другом скрипте верни это в переменную - пример:

include.php

```
<?php
    $var = 'PHP';
    return $var;
?>
```

script.php

```
<?php 
    $foo = include 'return.php';
    echo $foo; // выведет 'PHP'
?>
```

надеюсь именно это имелось в виду

Comment: пример взят с php.net

Comment: нет не то. у меня будет в этом файле только html код и мне нужно его в переменную загнать

Comment: html код это текст, который может быть представлен в виде строки, которая в свою очередь может быть значением переменной, 
т.е. в примере выше вместо 
$var = 'PHP' может быть
$var = '<title>Заголовок стартовой страницы</title>';
и будет вам возвращаться html

если это по какой-то причине не нравится, то используйте file_get_contents()

Answer (score 1):

Вам правда этого хочется?

```
ob_start();
include 'file.html';
$html = ob_get_clean();
```

Не проводя тестов готов спорить, что когда сравним, вышеупомянутый @xEdelweiss [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php) окажется быстрее.

**Upd.** А вот и [данные сравнения](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328301/is-file-get-contents-slower-than-include)! Второй ответ. От быстрого к тормозу:

1. file_get_contents()
2. readfile()
3. include

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное. Просто некоторые образованные люди мне говорят что то то то то грузит сервер и я иду сюда а в результате оказывается что ничего не грузит даже наоборот

Comment: Зачем ходить от одних «образованных» людей к другим? Проверить самому не так сложно : )

@Deert, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: посоветуйте прогу с помощью которой можно узнать скорость выполнения функции(скрипта)

Comment: В ответе ссылка "данные сравния" кликабельна. Там во втором ответе примеры кода. В PHP есть ф-я microtime() которая возвращает время с точностью до 1/1000 секунды. Запоминаете его до начала выполнения цикла в 100000 считываний файла одним из способов, и сравниваете со временем, измеренным сразу после.

Answer (score 0):

Пользуйтесь шаблонизатором. Он может и в переменную вернуть код шаблона.